# What's the difference between print and printf in awk?

Tags: awk

In `awk` what is the difference between `print` and `printf`?

Is there any restrictions to use only `print` instead of `printf` and vice-versa

Comment: Was it really too hard to read the manual for something like this?

Comment: @jasonwryan Agree- But if I repeatedly ask about something which is available at manual, your comment is more useful. But it was my first post. I t was very _odd_ behavior from technically sound person =)

Comment: Ravan, on U&L context is appreciated.  Such as: I am learning, saw this, tried that, this happened, I want to do this, why, and how?  Working examples to illustrate are great!  There are hundreds of perspectives on a question like yours --  a little context to get a direction and boot up an answer really helps.  Whatever makes you to wonder would be good to know.  I see you're a top member on AskUbuntu, welcome to U&L. I would say one way to think about the difference is that Ubuntu is a product, Unix is philosophy.

Comment: @jasonwryan I also think the question is too general.  But I see Ravan's point.  How about: "Most of what you're asking is covered in the `awk` manpage."  Can we judge what might be hard or easy for someone else?

Comment: @RobertL see the mouse over text for a downvote: "This question does not show any research effort..."

Comment: @jasonwryan I could see how that's appropriate here too and may be more direct and effective.  I'm curious about your reasons not to downvote?

Comment: @RobertL I did downvote (current count is -2 +2 = 0 ).

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry, I forgot about clickin that thing to see the totals.

Comment: @jasonwryan "This question does not show any research effort..." You mean just running `man awk` is a __good research effort__ ? Do you think the `man` page totally answer my question?

Comment: @Ravan reading the man page shows *some* research effort; that is not the same as "good research effort"...

Comment: @jasonwryan So if I mention: I have read `man` page shows some research, correct? So I can ask ?

Answer (score 8):

As the GNU awk (gawk manual says) at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printing

> Use the print statement to produce output with simple, standardized
>   formatting. You specify only the strings or numbers to print, in a
>   list separated by commas. They are output, separated by single spaces,
>   followed by a newline.

& etc.

> For more precise control over the output format than what is provided
>   by print, use printf. With printf you can specify the width to use for
>   each item, as well as various formatting choices for numbers (such as
>   what output base to use, whether to print an exponent, whether to
>   print a sign, and how many digits to print after the decimal point).

So this pretty much explains the differences and restrictions.

Comment: good answer but examples of print and printf would be better

Answer (score 5):

**print**:

- "Print" by itself prints the input line.
- "Print" with one argument prints the argument.
- "Print" with multiple arguments prints all the arguments, separated by spaces (or other specified OFS) when the arguments are separated by commas, or concatenated when the arguments are separated by spaces.

**printf**:

The "printf()" (formatted print) function is much more flexible, and trickier. It has the syntax:

```
 printf(<string>,<expression list>)
```

**Difference**:

The difference between printf and print is the format argument. This is an expression whose value is taken as a string; it specifies how to output each of the other arguments. It is called the format string.

References [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_7.html) and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer/Output_with_print_and_printf)